# How to show progress when checking checksums using sha256sum

Tags: debian, hashsum

How do I show the progress when when checking the SHA256 checksums of large files? When I do `sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS` where the file `SHA256SUMS` contains the checksum for a large file, there is no indication of when the command might finish. Is there a way to show progress when doing `sha256sum -c ...`?

Answer (score 9):

`sha256sum` belongs to GNU Coreutils. Most of them are missing a `--progress` or `status=progress` option (recent versions of `dd` provide one but `sha256sum` does not, cf. [git log](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git&a=search&h=HEAD&st=commit&s=progress))

Workarounds:

1. **There is `progress -w` (the Coreutils Progress Viewer).** It can run as a background process (or in a second terminal in combination with `watch`, e.g. `watch progress -w`):

   ```
   $ progress -w & sha256sum -c Fedora-Workstation-36-1.5-x86_64-CHECKSUM.txt
   [2] 58536
   [58537] sha256sum /home/user/Downloads/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-36-1.5.iso
           20.7% (398.1 MiB / 1.9 GiB) 383.3 MiB/s remaining 0:00:03
   ```

   If you are allowed to install it, it provides what you are searching for. It should be packaged on all major distros but is usually *not* installed by default, especially on minimal installs.
2. Last resort: `pv`. Sadly not replacing the functionality `sha256sum -c` (as it does not support multiple file not compares something automatically), but one can for sure use `pv` to pipe a file into `sha256sum`:

   ```
   $ pv Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-35-1.2.iso | sha256sum
   159GiB 0:00:04 [ 411MiB/s] [============================>      ] 85% ETA 0:00:02
   ```

   By default, `-p` and `-e` should be active options (giving you the progress bar and estimated time till finished). `pv` should be packaged for all major distros and is usually installed by default, even on minimal ones.

Comment: +1; Thanks for making me aware of `progress` :-)

Answer (score 1):

This has been tested on MacOS 10.15.7, using the bash shell. Other shells and other versions of MacOS should also work, but may not.

sha256sum takes standard input, so you can pipe a file through `pv` or some other progress checking filter:

`cat some_long_file_you_want_progress_on | pv | sha256sum`

According to the man page, "pv takes many options, which are divided into display switches, output modifiers, and general options."

Because piped data has no idea how long it is, if you want a percentage complete (instead of just some meaningless animation), you'll have to come up with a file size. If you know the size of your file, you can use the "-s" switch for pv:

`cat some_long_file_you_want_progress_on | pv -s 12345 | sha256sum`

If you're going to do this a lot, you can make it a shell function, so it can figure out the size of the file:

```
function sha_prog {
    cat $1 | pv -s $(du -sb $1 | awk '{print $1}') | sha256sum
}
```

Now, if you enter `sha_prog some_long_file_you_want_progress_on`, you'll get a percentage of completion animation as things happen.

This starts a pipeline with the contents of the first argument to the function ("some_long_file_you_want_progress_on"), pipes it to `pv -s` with the size of the file (`du`), then pipes it to `sha256sum`.

Note that `'{print $1}'` is protected by single quotes, so $1 **does not** get replaced by the file name; rather the actual characters "$1" are passed to `awk`, which interprets them to mean the first token in the input, since `du` prints both the file size and its name to standard output.

I have tested this and found it useful enough to add to my `~/.bashrc` so I can easily re-use it in the future. There are other pipeline progress indicators out there you can use, too!

Comment: How do I use this with `sha256sum -c ...`?

Comment: If, as your question states, you have a file with a single CRC in it, than simply put ` -c  SHA256SUMS` in the function after `sha256sum`.

Comment: I always use pv with `-petrab`. A nice combo of flags for the best verbosity.

Comment: @JanSteinman, `sha256sum` works, put `pv` does not print anything, when I simply put `-c SHA256SUMS` in the function after `sha256sum`.

Comment: @sudodus, perhaps check for typos? I tried it, and the `-c` option does not appear to mess with `pv`.

Comment: @JanSteinman, Please show exactly which command line to use, and I will try it. It is possible that I made a typo, it is also possible that our systems are different. (I believe you that it works for you, but for me there was no output from pv before the whole job was finished, so no progress view.)

Comment: I did the following two commands: `cat winehq-stable-5.0.pkg | pv | sha256sum >xxx` which writes the CRC to the file "xxx". It displayed progress while it worked. I then did `cat winehq-stable-5.0.pkg | pv | sha256sum -c xxx` which matched the checksum for that file with the one previously stored in "xxx", also showing progress, and printing "OK" with an execution return code of zero, meaning the CRCs were the same.

Comment: @JanSteinman, I ran it (with my input file), and with no progress indication during the process. There was an ''OK" and after that an output from `pv`, but that's too late (and indicated only 64KiB, when the file is 4.2GiB). I might as well use `time`. - So our systems act differently. Mine is based on Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS with the LXDE of that version of Lubuntu. What's your system? Are you doing something extra to make the output of `pv` show during the process?

Comment: MacOS 10.15.7. It would seem to me that something is working differently. Perhaps play with pv's `-B num` option, which causes it to report progress upon buffering so many characters? Or `-C`, which forces use of a transfer buffer, even if it could normally be bypassed? I can't fix it, 'cause it isn't broken here!

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to clearly state (near the top) that your solution is for macOS 10.15.7 (and that it may differ for other platforms).

Comment: @Greenonline: I don't know that is the case. `pv` and `cat` appear to be standard *NIX utilities. I would assume that my solution will work on earlier versions.

Comment: +1 for explaining where it works, and that you have tested it.

Answer (score 1):

#### This method uses `progress` and maybe `xterm` that need to be installed.

```
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS & pid=$! ; xterm -e progress -mp $pid 2>/dev/null
```

The progress is written to a separate window (of course there must be a graphical desktop). Otherwise

```
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS & progress -mp $!
```

will also work, but it overwrites the output, for example the confirmation `OK`, which you would like to see (not only flash by very quickly). So without using a separate window, instead of getting continuous updates of the progress, one single estimate of the remaining time is best, which is suggested in the answer by Andreas Haerter,

```
$ progress -w & sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS
[6] 9930
[ 9931] sha256sum /media/multimed-2/CD/ubuntu/22.04/ubuntustudio-22.04-dvd-amd64.iso
    5.1% (217.8 MiB / 4.1 GiB) 212.4 MiB/s remaining 0:00:18

ubuntustudio-22.04-dvd-amd64.iso: OK
```

I added a fix via temporary file, that makes the second method better, to avoid overwriting the output `OK`, also useful for a checksum file with several fairly large files,

```
md5sum -c md5sum.txt > /tmp/mytmp & progress -mp $! ; cat /tmp/mytmp
```

(This latest fix was tested in my directory with several compressed image files and corresponding md5sums, hence the switch from sha256sum, but the syntax is the same.)

#### This method is a workaround, that needs `pv` and `espeak` to be installed.

It is a workaround for `sha256sum -c`. First you must extract the relevant checksum from the checksum file and use it as the second parameter.

You may skip `espeak`, if you don't want a loud warning when there is a mismatch.

**Shellscript `sha256check-pv`:**

```
#! /bin/bash

namesum=$(basename $0)
namesum=${namesum/check/sum}
namesum=${namesum/-pv}
#echo $namesum

if [ "$2" == "" ]
then
 echo "Usage: $0 <file> <$namesum>"
 exit
fi

calcsum=$(pv "$1" | "$namesum" | cut -d " " -f1)
chksum="${2,,}"

echo "calculated $namesum=$calcsum"
echo "should be  $namesum=$chksum"

if [ "$calcsum" == "$chksum" ]
then
 echo "$0 indicates SUCCESSFUL download :-)"
else
 echo ":-( $0 indicates FAILED download :-("
 espeak -p 65 -s 120 -k10 -a 150 "Download failed" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
fi
```

**Examples:**

Using a correctly downloaded file and a correct checksum:

```
$ sha256check-pv ubuntustudio-22.04-dvd-amd64.iso 66a6c7e54c41e39b5e671cea65f3af635c26aa7c3b6983d8785970988a9ec0a2
4,14GiB 0:00:19 [ 212MiB/s] [========================================================================>] 100%            
calculated sha256sum=66a6c7e54c41e39b5e671cea65f3af635c26aa7c3b6983d8785970988a9ec0a2
should be  sha256sum=66a6c7e54c41e39b5e671cea65f3af635c26aa7c3b6983d8785970988a9ec0a2
/home/sudodus/bin/sha256check-pv indicates SUCCESSFUL download :-)
```

and when I change the last digit in the checksum

```
$ sha256check-pv ubuntustudio-22.04-dvd-amd64.iso 66a6c7e54c41e39b5e671cea65f3af635c26aa7c3b6983d8785970988a9ec0a1
4,14GiB 0:00:19 [ 212MiB/s] [========================================================================>] 100%            
calculated sha256sum=66a6c7e54c41e39b5e671cea65f3af635c26aa7c3b6983d8785970988a9ec0a2
should be  sha256sum=66a6c7e54c41e39b5e671cea65f3af635c26aa7c3b6983d8785970988a9ec0a1
:-( /home/sudodus/bin/sha256check-pv indicates FAILED download :-(
```